# Is it possible to use `org-ref` in LaTeX mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-ref

I love using `org-ref` in my `org` files, and then export them to PDF (or even LaTeX). However, I have a lot of LaTeX manuscript which I don't want to translate into `org`, and I could use an `org-ref`-like way of managing the references within these files.

### Question

Is is possible? And How?

Comment: You can use RefTeX. And this question might be more appropriate for TeX.SE

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with `org-ref`? As @mankoff points out, `reftex` generally serves the same purpose in `.tex` files that `org-ref` does in `.org` files.

Comment: `helm-bibtex` or `ivy-bibtex` might be a nice alternative that can be used in both org and tex.